# remove-duplicates produces numbers that haven't been in the original list in NetLogo

Tags: list, netlogo, drop-duplicates

I'm creating a list out of the patch variable "geb-id" (a 7-digit integer number) with the following line:

```
set geb-id-list [geb-id] of patches with [geb-id >= 0 AND residents != 0]
```

When I look at the produced list, all looks fine. Then I'm using

```
set geb-id-list remove-duplicates geb-id-list
```

to remove the duplicates, as there are several patches with the same `geb-id` but I only want one `geb-id` per list. The list now doesn't contain any duplicates anymore, but some of the numbers have turned into random floating point numbers and I cannot trace back where these numbers suddenly came from (I checked the source data and they don't contain any floating point numbers).

For example:

The list with duplicates:

```
[ 133349 133349 133351 133351 133351 133360 133360 133360 133375 133375 133375 ]
```

The list without duplicates:

```
[ 133349 133351 133360 209587.61538461538 133915.6666666667 1518018.2 133375 ]
```

The floating point numbers that appear in the list without duplicates do not appear in the original list (even when removing the digits after the comma).

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f92hfic3uz1hxne/geb-id-list.csv?dl=0) is the list with with the geb-id's as a csv file.

Comment: Is there any way you can post your source data as a CSV or the procedure that generates it (if it's not from a file)?  Running `show remove-duplicates [ 133349 133349 133351 133351 133351 133360 133360 133360 133375 133375 133375 ]` in the command center gives `[133349 133351 133360 133375]` as expected.

Comment: I can't provide the source data, but I used the csv:to-file function from the csv-extension to copy the original list into an excel file. I hoped that when I would read in the data again ( with csv:from-file) as a new list (and removing the "NaN" values) it would magically solve my problem. But it didn't, I still get the floating point numbers as soon as I apply the remove-duplicates function. I attached the csv-file in my question above.

Comment: Looking at your csv file, you do have some floating point numbers in there, for example 209587.615384615. You probably just formatted them in a way that rounds them to a whole number which is why you didn't notice them right away.

Comment: It's realllllllllllly unlikely that there's a bug in `remove-duplicates`, so you should do your best to absolutely rule out other explanations first.

Answer (score 2):

I think your source data does have floating point values in it.  When I use your provided CSV and run this code:

```
extensions [csv]

to check-floats
  let values-2d csv:from-file "geb-id-list.csv"
  let values map [ r -> item 0 r ] values-2d 
  let nums filter [ v -> v != "NaN" ] values
  let floats filter [ n -> floor n != n ] nums
  show floats
end
```

The `check-floats` outputs `[2079045.4999999998 2111524.956521739 862483.9473684211 361412.1111111111 1278359.6666666667 2111602.5 1564756.1249999998 2111443.4285714286 2150385.3333333335 134019.9090909091 2111560.285714286 2111643.75 133585.33333333334 134012.2 133580.00000000003 1518018.2 133915.6666666667 1452081.6666666665 133894.57142857145 ... ]`.

If you are loading in those geb-id's from an external source and you are *sure* there are no floats in that source data, then something in your NetLogo model code must be altering them to that format before you try to use `remove-duplicates` on them.  If you can't discover how the floats are getting in there, posting more of your model's code could help someone find the cause.